# Update function crashes program when called

Tags: android, sql, database, runtime-error

This is the update function I have but it crashes whenever i call to update an id.

```
public boolean UpdateData(String ID, String First, String Last, String MAKE, String MODEL, String Cost) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(ID, ID);
        cv.put(CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME, First);
        cv.put(CUSTOMER_LAST_NAME, Last);
        cv.put(CAR_MAKE, MAKE);
        cv.put(CAR_MODEL, MODEL);
        cv.put(COST, Cost);
        db.update(Table_name, cv, "ID = ?", new String[]{ID});
        return true;
```

for example if i am updating id 2 it will cause this error

```
Process: mbl402.phoenix.edu.week4appgk5343, PID: 3983
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "2": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE CUSTOMER_TABLE SET  2=?,Customer_First_Name=?,CAR_MAKE=?,Cost=?,CAR_MODEL=?,Customer_Last_Name=? WHERE ID = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out I had to take out the line 
cv.put(ID, ID);